# sharepoint foundation 2010 client object model gives the wrong Last Modified Time of the versions of files

Tags: sharepoint-2010

sharepoint foundation 2010 client object model gives the wrong Last Modified Time of the versions of files. How to get the correct modified time.

I am using the below code....

```
SP.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelatedUrl);
clientContext.Load(file, fv => fv.Name, fv => fv.Exists, fv => fv.TimeLastModified);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
SP.FileVersionCollection fileVersionCollection = file.Versions;
clientContext.Load(fileVersionCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (SP.FileVersion fileVersion in fileVersionCollection)
{
   clientContext.Load(fileVersion, fv => fv.Created);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   DateTime ModifiedTime = fileVersion.Created;
 }
```

Here fileVersion.Created give the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: Can you provide some examples of where it is wrong (and by how much) and what code you are using to get access to the times?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question...